# Populate multiple layout for a single cutom array adapter android

Tags: android, android-layout

It is possible to populate multiple layouts for a single custom arrayadapter in android. If not can I replace one widget eg. a swicth with a progressbar for different items of my list?

Or do I have to design a few different ArrayAdapter classes with different layouts?

Comment: You have to maintain a flag for it. You can check the type of data in inside getView() and put your condition to show the layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to maintain multiple layouts in single adapter. It is easy to maintain the layout view on the flag basis. You can also tag the different - 2 views with same holder and update these views as per your requirement.

I think tag multiple views with view holder is good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible to populate multiple layouts for a single custom arrayadapter in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Take one `interface` and write `functions` based on corresponding  layouts u need.Based on that u can implement `Adapter` with different layouts.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final Item i = (Item) data.get(position);

if (i.isSection1()) {

SectionItem si = (SectionItem) i;

view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

}else if(i.isSection2())
{

final ScheduleModel scheduleValues = (ScheduleModel) i;

view = vi.inflate(R.layout.schedule_list_item, null);

}

}
```